# ML Engine: Package libffi was not found

Tags: python, pip, cairo, google-cloud-ml, pycairo

I'm trying to train a model in ML Engine that uses the `cairocffi` python module, which has a dependency on something called `libffi`. In the logs I get the message `No package 'libffi' found`. Others who've had this problem solve it by executing `apt-get install libffi-dev` on their machine before running `pip install cairocffi`. Is there a way to install such a dependency for a ML Engine job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dependencies that can't be installed by pip, you can package them in a container and run it on Cloud ML Engine. How to run custom containers is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/custom-containers-training).